# Error: Arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 1, 2, 0

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I wrote this code to make a Boxplot tool for my team. It is currently a constant source of errors and frustration. I don't know where this problem is coming from but it seems likely that it is coming from the point where I am making a new data.frame. If anyone could point out where the problem is coming from and how to fix it, that'd be wonderful. Here's the code:

```
library(shiny)
All_Data <- data.frame(
    Name = as.character(c("2015 Acidobacteria C1", "2015 Acidobacteria C1", "2015 Acidobacteria C1", "2015 Acidobacteria C1", "2015 Actinobacteria C1")),
    Year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015,2015),
    Bacteria = as.factor(c("Acidobacteria", "Acidobacteria", "Acidobacteria", "Acidobacteria","Actinobacteria")),
    Site = as.factor(c("C1", "C1", "C1", "C1","C1")),
    Percents = as.numeric(c(5,2,3,5,5)),
    stringsAsFactors = TRUE
)
ndata <-data.frame(
    Name = as.character("Preset"),
    Year = c("0"),
    Bacteria = as.factor(c("0")),
    Site = as.factor(c("0")),
    Percents = as.numeric(c("0")),
    stringsAsFactors = TRUE
)

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Boxplot Maker"),

    # Sidebar
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            h3("Which Data Sets Would You Like to Compare?"),
            selectInput("Set1", "", choices = All_Data$Name),
            selectInput("Set2", "",choices = All_Data$Name),
            selectInput("factor","Based on Which Factor?", choices = c("Year", "Site", "Bacteria", "Site by Year", "Bacteria by Year", "Bacteria by Site by Year")),
            textInput("title", h4("Title"), value = "Enter title..."),
            actionButton("Submit", "Submit")
        ),

        # Show a chosen plot
        mainPanel(
        uiOutput("data"),
        tableOutput("plot")
            )
    )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$data <- renderUI(
        conditionalPanel( condition = "input.Submit >0",
                          ndata <- filter(All_Data, All_Data$Name == input$Set1 | All_Data$Name == input$Set2)
        
    ))
    output$plot <- renderTable(
        boxplot(All_Data$Percents ~ All_Data$Year, data = All_Data, main = input$title)
    )
   }

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Are you trying to draw a plot here? Right now you have `tableOutput` and `renderTable` which is meant to work with, well, tables. If you want a plot, it would make more sense to use `plotOutput` and `renderPlot()`

Comment: Please take a look here: https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/box-plot/

Comment: Also, you don't need to repeat the data frame name...for example: `boxplot(Percents ~ Year, data = All_Data, main = input$title)` should be sufficient